# Save document as PDF on Google Drive through Google Cloud Print in Chrome

Tags: google-drive, google-chrome, google-cloud-print

If you click on Print button (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>)
you would see print page where you can select the printer.

Among other, local printers there is an option: *Print with Google Cloud Print*

by clicking of which you would see your **Cloud Print** printers.

But there also an option (on that **Cloud Print** printers selection popup)
called: **Save to Google Drive** (Save your document as a PDF in **Google Drive**)

When you click on that option the **Print** button would become available which should mean that the document is ready to be saved as PDF on **Google Drive**. However, after clicking on print button it thinks a little bit and the popup closes. Normally I was expecting that the doc is successfully saved in Google Drive, while, in fact, it wasn't.

I am using the latest (just upgraded: 12 July 2012) **Google Chrome** on **Linux**

I don't understand what I did wrong.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have an answer, but I have the same issue when attempting to print using Google Cloud Print to Google Docs, and opening up through Google Drive on my iPad. I can see the file in there, but the content is blank. This makes no sense to me.

Comment: so this is, apparently, a bug then? Are you using Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't show up, but if you search for the document you can find it in Google Drive.  It seems like a bug to me...

To see what it was saved as, try visiting here: https://www.google.com/cloudprint/#jobs

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed that saving a document as PDF to Google Drive this way will give the document an URL as its name, and doesn't show up automatically in the recent files list.

If you search your Drive for [https](https://drive.google.com/?authuser=0#search/https) you'll get results, the first one likely being the document you just saved.

You can right-click that, then rename it. Once it's been renamed it shows up in your recent files list.

Answer (score -1):

You need to click on Activity right above the Off-line icon on your Google Drive

Comment: Can you show us? Then it wouldn't be a oneliner.

Answer (score -1):

iPad Air.
Was having the same trouble. If you have google drive open the list of files only, press the exclamation mark of the document you want to pdf, wait for options box, select > open with. I have an app called pdf printer $, (should be free ones out there) the document then opens in the app as a pdf. Can be emailed direct from app. 
Hope that helps. 
Michael

Comment: What does this have to do with an iPad Air?